# BeautifulSoup + Python (Extract Specific HTML Tags from Page Source Code)

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have the following HTML Code:

```
<h3>Some Heading Text Here 1</h3>
<p>Some paragraph text here</p>
<p>Some paragraph text here</p>
<p>Some paragraph text here</p>
<ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
</ul>
<h3>Some Heading Text Here 2</h3>
<p>Some paragraph text here</p>
<p>Some paragraph text here</p>
<h4>Q1</h4>
<p>A1</p>
<h4>Q2</h4>
<p>A2</p>
<h4>Q3</h4>
<p>A3</p>
```

I would like to pull HTML from 1st `<h3>` and its child until the first occurrence of `<h4>` tag.

Expected Output:

```
<h3>Some Heading Text Here 1</h3>
<p>Some paragraph text here</p>
<p>Some paragraph text here</p>
<p>Some paragraph text here</p>
<ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
</ul>
<h3>Some Heading Text Here 2</h3>
<p>Some paragraph text here</p>
<p>Some paragraph text here</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried following, and it worked out:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = """<h3>Some Heading Text Here 1</h3>
<p>Some paragraph text here</p>
<p>Some paragraph text here</p>
<p>Some paragraph text here</p>
<ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
</ul>
<h3>Some Heading Text Here 2</h3>
<p>Some paragraph text here</p>
<p>Some paragraph text here</p>
<h4>Q1</h4>
<p>A1</p>
<h4>Q2</h4>
<p>A2</p>
<h4>Q3</h4>
<p>A3</p>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data)

tags = soup.find_all('h3')

text = ""
for i in tags:
    # print(i)
    text = text+str(i)
    for x in i.next_siblings:
        
        if x.name == 'h4':
            break
        else:
            text = text+str(x)
print(text)
```

Output:

```
<h3>Some Heading Text Here 1</h3>
<p>Some paragraph text here</p>
<p>Some paragraph text here</p>
<p>Some paragraph text here</p>
<ul>
<li>Item 1</li>
<li>Item 2</li>
<li>Item 3</li>
<li>Item 4</li>
</ul>
<h3>Some Heading Text Here 2</h3>
<p>Some paragraph text here</p>
<p>Some paragraph text here</p>
<h3>Some Heading Text Here 2</h3>
<p>Some paragraph text here</p>
<p>Some paragraph text here</p>
```